# tracking a phone using javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gps, smartphone

I am building a website to manage and maintain vehicles belongs to a company. There is  a feature to track particular vehicle using smart phone which belongs to the vehicle. All vehicles have a smart phone with internet connection and GPS on. Is there any way to do this using javascript or JQuery?

Comment: what is it currently outputting?

Comment: No difference between `f` and `g`, apart from the name of the local variable `p` vs `y`. Both invoke UB as answered already. Neither bodes with the title of your question `different between & and *?`.

Comment: For most cases, `&` is _address of_ and `*` is _value at_.

Comment: There should be a close reason for obvious UB, especially when the compiler says something like: *"warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'p' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]"*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 5):

first of all, let me tell you, both of your functions invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you `return` the address of a local variable and you try to use the `return` value in the caller.

Once the functions will finish their execution, the local variables will cease to exist and the returned address(es) will become *invalid*. If you want to have the returned address to remain in scope, you need to define a pointer and allocate dynamic memory to them. Maybe you can have a look at the [man page of `malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family to get an idea.

---

That said, FWIW, the `&` is called *address-of* operator, and the properties are mentioned in chapter §6.5.3.2, `C11` standard

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
>   `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
>   not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

and

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’,
>   the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’.

Then, the `*` is called indirection operator and the properties are

> The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type. [...]

and

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
>   a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
>   object. If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. [..]